# Hibernate lazy-initialize object which cannot be handled

Tags: hibernate, lazy-evaluation

I have the entity "TipoCartera" which has a lazy relationship with the entity "TipoServicio".

I initialize the TipoServicio entity by `getHibernateTemplate().initialize(tipoCartera.getTipoServicio());`

Taking a look on the eclipse debbuger I can see the initialized variable is setted to "true" and the handler is correctly but I cannot access to the data of "TipoServicio", if I do 
`tipoCartera.getTipoServicio().getId()` it returns "null".

TipoCartera entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TTipoCartera.NOMBRETABLA)
public class TipoCartera extends ModelBase {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = TTipoCartera.IDLIBTIPOSERVICIO)
    /** Identificador del tipo de servicio al que está asociado la cartera. */
    private TipoServicio tipoServicio;
```

TipoServicio entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TTipoServicio.NOMBRETABLA)
public class TipoServicio extends ModelBase {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tipoServicio")
    /** Lista de tipos de cartera que están asociadas al servicio. */
    private List<TipoCartera> lTiposCarteras;
```

Any idea?

Thank you!!

Comment: In cartera.getTipoServicio().getId(), id is primary key?

Comment: Could you try Hibernate.initialize()

Comment: Yes is the primary key from TipoServicio entity, I can see this value on the debbuger.

Comment: Zeus I do Hibernate.initialize(tipoCartera.getTipoServicio()) and it works correctly, the problem is when I do getId() and it returns "null"

Comment: Are you processing objects you just created in the application layer? If so, you will need to do a save repository before the ids are generated.

Comment: @Jose, is `tipoCartera` and `cartera` same in your question?

Comment: Yes, cartera and tipoCartera are from the same class. I've edited the post to avoid confusion. Thank you

Comment: @Avik I don't understand your question completly but I have the persistent layer. It works fine, I can get the data from DB, the lazy object is initialized correctly, I can see in the debbuger the data in the target property of the lazy object but when I try to get any data from this object it always returns me null.